# Background color in cells in a table

Tags: r, officer

I am creating tables using flextable and officer.  I would like to apply conditional formatting to cells, e.g., if a value is > 1.5, apply a colored background.  I understand how to color entire rows or columns but not individual cells.  Is this possible?

Comment: Take a look at the `conditional formatting` section of flextable vignette https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flextable/vignettes/format.html

Answer (score 4):

Using the `airquality`  dataset to demonstrate conditional formatting of cell :

```
library(flextable)

#https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flextable/vignettes/format.html
df<- datasets::airquality
ft<- flextable(df)
ft<- bg(ft, bg = "#E4C994", part = "header")
ft<- bg( ft, bg = "#99CCFF", part = "body")
#conditional formatting : 
#i is row , conditional . j is column 
bg(ft, i = ~ Temp>70, 
      j = ~ Temp, 
      bg="red")
```

The result would be :

[image]