# How to remove table background in gtsummary or flextable?

Tags: r, flextable, gtsummary, quarto

So I'm trying to report some results with Quarto and rendering it to MSword. I want to remove the background of my tables output. Here is an example:

````
```{r}
#| echo: false
#| warning: false
#| error: false
#| label: tbl-coef
#| tbl-cap: "Coeficiente de regressão" 
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)
library(flextable)
lm(price~carat,data=diamonds) %>% tbl_regression() %>%  as_flex_table()
```
````

When I open my MSword document the tables are shown with a white background, instead of editing each table I would like to find a way to change this layout in my code.

Comment: What color do you want as a background color?

Comment: Have you checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64527438/background-color-in-cells-in-a-table)?

Comment: @Julian I want it with no color (transparent) in the bg.

Comment: The background is at the moment white and you want transparant bg?

Comment: Thats it. I'm doing a rmarkdown document  and I need it to be transparant bg